# App structure, modules and their upgrades

Tags: angularjs

Learning Angular and experiencing it for the first time, I'm still not sure I understand Modules. I need your help to look at my app's structure and see if I do.

Browsing for some Angular good practices guidance, I came across John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide). Reading through styles [151](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y151), [152](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y152), [163](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y163), [165](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y165) made me become unsure if I fully understand the role of modules when there's a need for parallel development; how a new module (after a development sprint for example), which should be an upgrade for an existing module, is integrated into the angular app with "little or no friction".

Please look at the following app structure.

[image: My app's structure]

To try keep it up the par with the guides (again, to my understanding), I've created a parent folder for each feature (component) of the app. For example, for the 'footer' and 'header' layout features, I've created 'footers' and 'headers' grouping folders.

I did this because if I want to have a **app.layout** module with controllers for header and footer (like the style guide recommends), and someday I will want to change those parts of the site - I need to be able to develop a new **app.newLayout** module without affecting the old module.

But even still, changing the dependency of my app from app.layout module to app.newLayout module still needs work, not sure if it should: I still need to change my routing system (I use ngNewRouter by the way) and make it point to the new header and footer feature folders under layout/headers and layout/footers, respectively.

Turning to the guide again, 163 more specifically:

> Create modules that represent feature areas, such as layout, reusable and shared services, dashboards, and app specific features (e.g. customers, admin, sales).
>
> Why?: Self contained modules can be added to the application with little or no friction.
>
> Why?: Sprints or iterations can focus on feature areas and turn them on at the end of the sprint or iteration.

Does the change of dependency and routing system are the ones considered by the guide as "no friction"?